# Loading dompdf from subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, dompdf

I can't seem to target files outside the dompdf folder, I figured out I'd need the `$dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);`
 setting to allow the script to process other pages on the site, but still no luck. This is my code so far;

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF;
$dompdf->set_option( 'isRemoteEnabled', true );
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/test.html");
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$dompdf->stream('test');
```

This gives the following output:

> **Warning**: file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/test.html): failed
>   to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in
>   /home/sites/www.example.com/web/wp-content/plugins/example/incl/dompdf.php
>   on line 40
>
> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'Dompdf\Exception' with message
>   'Requested HTML document contains no data.' in
>   /home/sites/www.example.com/web/wp-content/plugins/example/incl/dompdf/src/Frame/FrameTree.php:146
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/sites/www.example.com/web/wp-content/plugins/example/incl/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php(572):
>   Dompdf\Frame\FrameTree->build_tree() #1
>   /home/sites/www.example.com/web/wp-content/plugins/example/incl/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php(722):
>   Dompdf\Dompdf->processHtml() #2
>   /home/sites/www.example.com/web/wp-content/plugins/example/incl/dompdf.php(43):
>   Dompdf\Dompdf->render() #3 {main} thrown in
>   /home/sites/www.example.com/web/wp-content/plugins/example/incl/dompdf/src/Frame/FrameTree.php
>   on line 146

The called test.html exists and is reachable by the browser. If I replace that URL with something else like Google or Yahoo, it also does work.
What am I missing, is this a server configuration issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, the code is working. On the development server there was a htaccess blocking requests:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^$ keep_out
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (pycurl|casper|cmsworldmap|diavol|dotbot) keep_out
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (flicky|ia_archiver|kmccrew) keep_out
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (purebot|comodo|feedfinder|planetwork) keep_out
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=keep_out
```

Removed that, and it worked. Must be monday.